# form elements appear transparent when combining vue material and the vue cli webpack template

Tags: css, vue.js, vue-cli, vue-material

I have a problem when using `md-buttons`, `md-select` or `md-field` in a vue project created by the vue CLI from the webpack template.

I have a MWE of the situation [here](https://github.com/FirefoxMetzger/vue-material-mwe), featuring the three introduction examples from the vue material website on each type of form item combined with the vue-cli template. It doesn't look very nice, but if you run it it breaks down as follows:

1. The first row are a set of radio buttons; however, the buttons are invisible (yet you can click on them, get a ripple effect and the correct value is recorded by vue)
   [image: An image of the problem with radio buttons]
2. Next is a select box; however, the background of the box is transparent. [image: Problem with select box]
3. Finally there are a few text boxes; however, the outlines seem to be transparent.
   [image: problem with the text boxes]

I can solve the issue with the select boxes by inserting a style block

```
<style>
  .md-menu-content-container {
    background-color: white;
  }
</style>
```

and that will make `md-select` work as expected. I still decided to include it here, because it seems related to the other issues and may have a common origin.

Unfortunately, I have not figured out how to solve the other issues yet or which attribute to modify to "patch" the problem. So any help or pointers are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that when using he latest version of `vue-material`, the default template has to be loaded explicitly. Hence adding

```
import 'vue-material/dist/theme/default.css'
```

to the `main.js` file from `vue-cli` seems to fix this issue.